# How to get a list off directories that match an pattern and iterate overt this dirs in gihub actions?

Tags: bash, shell, github-actions

I'm trying to get a list of dirs inside a certain dir that match a pattern, but no success, it is returning an empty list:

```
      - name: Run tests in all lambdas
        if: steps.changes.outputs.layers == 'true'
        run: |
          dirs=(test/lambdas/pre-*)
          for dir in dirs; do
            echo "Running command in $dir"
            if [ -d "$dir" ]; then
              (
                cd "$dir" &&
                yarn &&
                yarn prettier:check &&
                yarn build:check &&
                yarn test
              ) || echo "An error occurred in $dir"
            fi
          done
```

How can I get the list of dirs with this name pattern `pre-*` then iterate over each matching dir and do some actions ?

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) finds a serious problem in the Bash code (bad use of `dirs`).  The report that it produces includes a link to more information about the problem and how to fix it.  It's a good idea to run [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) on all new and modified shell code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> for dir in dirs; do
> ```

Iterates over **one string** `dirs`. Expand `dirs` bash array to iterate over it.

```
for dir in "${dirs[@]}"; do
```

Research a bash array introduction. Overall, just:

```
for dir in test/lambdas/pre-*; do
```